# AS3 Android Air, audio stream error

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, audio

I have a Android Actionscript project that I am trying to incorporate sound in, but having a problem that I cannot figure out.  I have the sound file in the same directory as my class file and my .xfl file.  I am trying to start the music file as soon as the application starts via class reference, but am getting the same error everytime:

```
  Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
  at playAudio()[C:\pathtoerror\playAudio.as:9]
  at networkScores/frame1()[networkScores::frame1:7]
```

Here is my class file:

```
package  
{
   import flash.media.Sound;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.media.SoundChannel;

   public class playAudio extends Sound
   {
         public var music:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("mathHomeSong.mp3"));
         public var sc:SoundChannel;
         public var num:int;

        public function playAudio(controlNum:int) 
        {
           num = controlNum;

           if(num == 1)
           {
              sc = music.play();
           }
           else if(num == 2)
           {

           }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is my call from the timeline:

```
  import playAudio;
  var playMusic:playAudio = new playAudio(1);
```

Just figured this out, I had to put a link to the mp3 file in my server, instead of putting it in my directory.
Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted too soon.  I just figured out my question, figures.  Ok, so what I did not do is post this file on my server and with the URLRequest(""); I had to put a link to my file on my server, not linki

The answer to this question is that I forgot to add this music file to a server and then link it via hyper link. For example http://mysite.com/audio.file

Sorry about this

thanks